# Using built in Windows Methods to get Contents of Folder

Tags: c++, windows

My goal is to only use built in methods of C++/Windows (I don't think std::filesystem is supported on my version of C++) to get the filenames within a folder.

right now I have this:

```
HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    hFind = FindFirstFile("C:\\Folder\\*", &data);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            //Process File Name
            std::wstring ws(data.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
```

Which seems to be returning blank names and not the names of the files in the folder.

Am I using this FindFirstFile function correctly? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @HansPassant since Win95, `*` works just fine to find files with extensions, `*` and `*.*` are actually the same as far as `FindFirstFile()` is concerned. Per [Wildcards in Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2017/06/04/wildcards-in-windows/): "*`'*'` gives you all files. `'*.*'` gives you ... all files*". Per [How did wildcards work in MS-DOS?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=24143): "*you’ll also discover that `*.*` is the same as `*` by itself*".

Answer (score 2):

Your code can't compile as shown. You are calling the ANSI version of `FindFirstFile()` (by virtue of you passing it a narrow ANSI string literal instead of a wide Unicode string literal), and `std::wstring` does not have a constructor that accepts a `char[]` as input.

Baring that mistake, you are also ignoring the `data.dwFileAttributes` field to distinguish between files and subfolders, and in the case of subfolders you are not checking the contents of `data.cFileName` to ignore the `"."` and `".."` special folder names.

Try this:

```cpp
WIN32_FIND_DATAW data;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(L"C:\\Folder\\*", &data);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        if ((data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
        {
            // Process File Name
            std::wstring ws(data.cFileName);
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            if ((lstrcmpW(data.cFileName, L".") != 0) &&
                (lstrcmpW(data.cFileName, L"..") != 0))
            {
                // Process Folder Name
                std::wstring ws(data.cFileName);
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &data));
    FindClose(hFind);
}
```